# Create php files from array

Tags: php

The following code when executed will create a file NewFileName.php
It will also add content to the page including adding the new file name within the content where I have $pagename.

This all works but my question is can I make multiple files from an array?

So for example

```
$pagename = array(“fileone”,”filetwo”,”filethree”,”filefour”);
```

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$pagename = "NewFileName";

$newFileName = '../folder/filename-'.$pagename.".php";
$newFileContent = '<?php $pagetitle = "Title '.$pagename.'"; $keywords = "Keywords '.$pagename.'"; $description = "Description about the page'.$pagename.'."; $ads = file_get_contents("../ads/square.php"); include("../include/head.php"); ?>


<?php include("../include/sidebar-anagram.php");?>    

<?php include("../include/foot.php"); ?>';

if (file_put_contents($newFileName, $newFileContent) !== false) {
    echo "File created (" . basename($newFileName) . ")";
} else {
    echo "Cannot create file (" . basename($newFileName) . ")";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. PHP offers a way to loop through the given array and do something for each item in that array.

For example:

```
// Please note that I've changed the variable name to the plural version of the word.
$pagenames = array("fileone","filetwo","filethree","filefour");
foreach($pagenames as $pagename) {
    // Do some stuff here.
}
```

Have a look here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

And also here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp